# OSGi Accessing Java EE within an Application Server

Tags: jakarta-ee, osgi

I have started looking at the OSGi and agreed that it is way forward because it gives you great extensibility by just packaging your stuff according to the bundle specs.  Anyway....my requirement is that currently I have my Java runtime and some services which uses Java EE services like JCA and JMS Server to process the requests within in an Application Servers like jBoss, WebLogic, GlassFish and WebSphere....I want to make and deploy my services as an OSGi bundles....but Is there anyway I can access Java EE resources from within my OSGi container? Otherwise I have to wrap everything (my runtime, web client etc) as an OSGi bundles which I want to avoid because of following reasons;

1. It will take an ages
2. I will loose all my Java EE functionalities which is not desirable
3. Seems like writing and testing everything from scratch.

I have searched a lot but couldn't find any solution and all the post regarding this point are at-least 3years old. Can someone guide me to the right direction and point me to some latest advancements in this area.

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

You could embed OSGi and publish the Java EE resources as services into the OSGi framework. I wrote a blog post on this topic which may help: http://njbartlett.name/2011/03/07/embedding-osgi.html

Answer (score 1):

If you search for 'enterprise OSGi' you may have more luck and get some more ideas. Many of the main application servers, including WebSphere, Glassfish, and JBoss now support integration between OSGi and Java EE components. One option is to use a JNDI bridge which allows your OSGi services to be looked up using JNDI. Another is to use SCA to connect things together. Apache Aries' SPI-fly project also allows you to expose META-INF/services as OSGi services.

Answer (score 1):

The [Enterprise OSGI spec](http://www.osgi.org/wiki/uploads/News/2010_03_23_OSGi_Releases_Enterprise_Specification.pdf) is geared towards leveraging enterprise services. Read the [Enterprise OSGi in Action](http://www.manning.com/cummins/) book.

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish server is built using OSGi, and now supports nice integration between OSGi and Java EE services. It exposes APIs to access Java EE services as OSGi services and also supports a so called Hybrid Application bundle where you can seamlessly use OSGi services in your Java EE application. Refer to this document for more details:

[OSGi Development using GlassFish](http://glassfish.java.net/public/GF-OSGi-Features.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The SpringSource dm Server, or dm Server for short, is the runtime portion of the SpringSource Application Platform. It is a lightweight, modular, OSGi-based runtime that provides a complete packaged solution for developing, deploying, and managing enterprise applications. By leveraging several best-of-breed technologies and improving upon them, the dm Server offers a compelling solution to develop and deploy enterprise applications

you can get more infos at [spring page](http://static.springsource.com/projects/dm-server/1.0.x/programmer-guide/html/ch03s02.html)